# Using Redis on Gitlab CI for a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, jwt

I am trying to set up Gitlab CI for my Rails project and for this I need Redis. I have added redis to the config file but I am getting an error

```
Redis::CannotConnectError:
  Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

I am using `JWTSession` for token-based authentication and this relies on Redis. This is my setup.

#### .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: ruby:2.5.1

services:
  - postgres:10.1
  - redis:latest

variables:
  BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
  DISABLE_SPRING: 1
  DB_HOST: postgres
  REDIS_URL: redis

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install nodejs -y
  - bundle check || bundle install --jobs $(nproc)
  - cp config/database.yml.ci config/database.yml
  - bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
  - bundle exec rails db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test

stages:
  - test

Tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec spec/
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

#### config/initializers/redis.rb

```
require 'redis'
$redis = Redis.new(url: 'redis://redis:6379/0')
```

#### config/initializers/jwt_sessions.rb

```
JWTSessions.encryption_key = Rails.application.credentials.secret_jwt_encryption_key
JWTSessions.token_store = :redis, {
  redis_url: 'redis://localhost:6379',
  token_prefix: 'jwt_'
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work. Any hint will be appreciated. Thank you!

#### UPDATE

I've just tried the `connect` block, but got this error:

```
connect:
  # Connect to PostgreSQL database as user postgres, without password
  image: redis
  script:
  - redis-cli -h redis PING
```

```
Redis::CannotConnectError:
        Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
--- Caused by: ---
      # Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL:
      #   Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for [::1]:6379
```

Comment: Did you try adding the `connect` block like in the example project?
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/redis/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: @MatthieuLibeer I've just tried it and got an error. I've put it in the update in my question.

Comment: It looks like you need to set the `REDIS_URL` environment variable to let Rails talk to Redis. See See the full conversation here: https://github.com/dokku/dokku-redis/issues/114

Comment: I don't have ENV["REDIS_URL"] in my application even though the redis gem says the env variable is provided. How and where should I use the env var?

Comment: Did you resolve the problem? I'm running into the same error now

Comment: @JanKrupa yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

This is my final .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: "ruby:2.4.0"

services:
  - postgres:latest
  - redis:latest
  - name: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.4
    alias: elasticsearch

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: lauber_backend_test
  POSTGRES_USER: runner
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
  REDIS_HOST: redis
  REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
  ELASTICSEARCH_URL: "http://elasticsearch:9200"

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq nodejs libpq-dev cmake libicu-dev
  - echo "$RAILS_MASTER_KEY" -> config/master.key
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle install --jobs $(nproc)  "${FLAGS[@]}"
  - cp config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
  - RAILS_ENV=test rails db:setup

rspec:
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec
```

Plus sidekiq config

```
redis = { db: 4, url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = redis
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = redis
end
```

I think the problem was with REDIS_URL env var not set in my sidekiq config.